# Keeping track of value from select - AngularjS

Tags: angularjs

What I am trying to do is have a dropdown option with "tags". When a tag is selected, items from my ng-repeat will either show or hide depending on if one of their tag's matches the selected tag.

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the currently selected tag value.

In my controller I have

```
// Items that are shown or hidden if the selected tag, matches one of theirs.
$scope.items = [
    {
      source: "../assets/images/FirstItem.png",
      tags: ["All","App","Dat","Man"]
    },
    {
     source: "../assets/images/SecondItem.png",
     tags: ["All","App"]
    }
  ];

  // All the possible tags (what populates the select/dropdown)
  $scope.tags = [
    {
      name:"All",
      tag:"All",
    },
    {
      name:"Applications",
      tag:"App"
    },
    {
      name:"Data Center",
      tag:"Dat",
    }
  ];

  // Updates the currentTag, so I can filter the items.
  $scope.newTag = function($scope) {
    $scope.currentTag = $scope.selectedItem.tag;
  };

  // Is the currently selected tag
  $scope.currentTag = "All";
```

My HTML

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-change="newTag()" ng-model="currentTag.tag">{{tag.name}}</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
      <img src="{{item.source}}" ng-show="somehow filter by currentTag" />
  </div>
</div>
```

So my problem is a simple way to keep track of the currently selected tag. Or from the select area, the tag.tag. I have been trying several examples of similar questions but nothing seems to work for me, I assume I am missing something simple as I am still new to AngularJS.

I have setup this up poorly, I am always open to improvements/proper coding!

Comment: Use `ng-options`, not `<option ng-repeat` `<select ng-options="tag as tag.name for tag in tags" ng-model="currentTag.tag" ng-change="newTag()"></select>`

Comment: Thanks! If you toss it into an answer I will accept! Also for ng-repeat, is putting an ng-show on each item an okay way to filter them out as I placeholder'ed above?

Comment: Posted a quick answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ng-options` with the `select` element:

```
<select ng-options="tag as tag.name for tag in tags" ng-model="currentTag.tag" ng-change="newTag()"></select>
```

Comment: Will accept when the timer expires! Any hints on how to do my filtering question? Just use something like ng-show one each element or what?

Comment: @Austin -- Either `ng-show` - or use the actual `filter` inside `ng-repeat` - `ng-show` is probably the easier way to go tho: `ng-show="currentTag.tag == item.tag"`

Comment: That's what I figured too, however my `item` can have multiple tags. I am not sure if AngularJS has some `contains` option. As just using the above code does not work since `item.tag` is an array of tags.

Comment: @Austin -- Why not `indexOf` - `ng-show="item.tag.indexOf(currentTag.tag) > -1"` - won't work if `tag` is an object tho, you may need a custom function, then you can use `Array.some` to find if a tag is contained in the list.

Comment: Got it! Just realized I had named my object property `tags`, not `tag` haha. Thanks!